# Amazon EventBridge - Rotation Succeeded Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create a rule that will trigger everytime AWS Secrets Manager Rotation is succeeded. However the rule was not triggered even though Rotation Succeeded Event is log in Event History.

Here's my event pattern:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "RotationSucceeded"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my event pattern? I tried PutSecretValue event and it is working, only in RotationSucceeded is not working. Thanks

Comment: How do you know it was not triggered? What is your target?

Comment: @Marcin will send a message to Amazon SQS, no message has been received after RotationSucceeded event has been created.

Comment: What is your SQS permissions policy?

Comment: @Marcin here's my permission. I haven't changed anything to it after i created my queue. 

https://ibb.co/bbRhPWj

Comment: Ok. Did you create CloudTrial trial?

Comment: @Marcin no. i only created eventbridge rule and sqs. On cloudtrail event history, I can see eventname with RotateSucceeded

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: How did you manage to solve it? we are having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `AWS API Call via CloudTrail` in EB, you **must** enable [CloudTrial trial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-ct-api-tutorial.html):

> To record events with a detail-type value of AWS API Call via CloudTrail, a **CloudTrail trail** with logging enabled **is required**.

Comment: My bad, it is not api call via cloudtrail. I guess i wasn't able to edit the detailt type upon exploring. However i solve the problem by adding this
 "source": ["aws.secretsmanager"]
on event pattern. Thanks and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

detail-type needs to be "AWS Service Event via CloudTrail"

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS Service Event via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "RotationSucceeded"
    ]
  }
}
```